# Maximum power allowance for server rack

Tags: cisco, dell, electrical-power

I have a server rack which consists of the following items

1) [1 x Cisco 3750V2 Layer 3 switch (24 ports)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-3750-series-switches/data_sheet_c78-531031.html)

2) [3 x Dell Power Edge R720](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/dell-poweredge-r720-spec-sheet.pdf)

I am not sure which criteria I should be looking for to calculate the maximum power allowance for this server.

In the Cisco case, should I look at

1) Power Supply rated Maximum??

2) Power supply??

3) Measured 100% Throughput Power Consumption (with Maximum PoE Loads)??

4) AC Input Voltage and Current??

I am confused over which criteria I should be looking at. Assumptions can be made to simplify the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use real or observed numbers...

Likely 400 Watts per server (assuming sane RAM and disk configurations) and ~380 Watts for the switch.

This is based on experience with the equipment in production and working in and around data centers.

Plan for expansion and growth as well.

Comment: "Observed or real numbers" as in run the server and see what's the power consumption ??

Comment: Yep. That's correct.

Comment: Note that POE switches are a whole different beast and can easily pull north of 700W when fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The Dell servers come with a range of power options, you have to look at your exact equipment.

The router can't deliver more than it's power supply can draw, so use the power supply rated maximum.

Your electrical supply needs to handle everything at max, I'd be generous if possible as all equipment tends to expand. A was recently advised by a Seagate building engineer to record the power information for every piece of equipment, he was helping me plan a cooling system.